# Finding greatest common divisor between two polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, factoring

I have the following past exam question:

> Calculate $\operatorname{gcd}(x^3 + 2x^2 + 2,2x^2 + 1)$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$

Now I haven't encountered this sort of gcd before(usually I am trying to solve linear Diophantine equations with Euclidian algorithm).

I have computed $\cfrac{x^3 + 2x^2 + 2}{2x^2 + 1}$

Which yielded $1 + \frac x2 + \frac{2-x}{4x^2 + 2}$

But I don't think this helps, and factorizing $2x^2 + 1$ is complex, so I am not sure what to do. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this "Abstract Algebra"?

Comment: @Deepak By your comment, probably not, but it was assessed in an abstract algebra course, so I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your divisions should not have any denominator because you should be using the Euclidean algorithm to find a quotient and remainder.  I'm sure you have done this with both integers and polynomials at school.  In this case, you have to remember to do arithmetic with the coefficients modulo $3$.  **Hint**: the first step is
$$x^3 + 2x^2 + 2=(2x^2 + 1)(2x+1)+(x+1)\ .$$

Comment: Your first equality is not true?
$(2x^2)(2x+1) + (x+1) =4x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 2$?

Comment: **Arithmetic modulo 3** means that $4$ is the same as $1$.

Comment: That makes sense, sorry. Why must we work in mod 3? Is this general, or case dependent?

Comment: That's what the question means when it says "in $\Bbb F_3$".

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Even though I imagine this problem is trivial. I am having trouble solving it. Does the solution continue as follows:

$2x^2 + 1 = 2x(x+1) + (x + 1)$

$(x+1) = 1*(x+1) * 0$, hence (x+1) is the gcd?

Comment: That's kind of correct, but better would be $2x^2+1=(x+1)(2x+1)$ with zero remainder.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Will there be cases where it is not obvious what to factor?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  Remember that ideally, your remainder should always have degree less than the divisor, that's why $2x^2+1=2x(x+1)+(x+1)$ was not so good.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, good rule!